# Determine connections between calls in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to find out which two calls in my Twilio account are connected to each other? Basically I have a queue which callers are enqueued into, and then operators which dial into the queue to answer calls.

Does Twilio keep track of which calls are connected to each other or do I have to do that manually?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

So when you bridge two calls together, the second leg of the call should include an attribute named ParentCallSid.  This is the CallSid of the call that initiated the `<Dial>` to the second leg.

So for example, lets say you have a customer Alice who is waiting in a queue, and agent Bob calls in to that Queue.  You use the `<Dial>` verb with the `<Queue>` noun to connect Bob to Alice.  In this case, once Bob and Alice are connected, you could use the REST API to get the details for Alices call which includes the ParentCallSid parameter which is Bobs call sid.

`<Dial>` reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial

`<Queue>` reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Devin, thanks for the response. Unfortunately this isn't what I'm seeing. Both calls have an empty ParentCallSid

Comment: I'm using the MVC library to enqueue the client and then connect the client using the dial verb. I've not written the code to look up the call details, I'm using the API explorer to view the call details and the XML in there doesn't include the ParentSid either during the call or after the call

Comment: @DevinRader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376053/implementing-twilios-incoming-calling-code-from-activity-into-service-class-but#comment50866215_31376053